# PlatformException(FitKit, 5000: Application needs OAuth consent from the user, null, null) when getting heart rate value from Google Fit

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0, google-fit

I am trying to get heart rate data from Google Fit using this codes:

```
void addBPM(List<FitData> results) {
    setState(() {
      results.where((data) => !data.userEntered).forEach((result) =>
      _heartBPM = result.value.round());
    });
  }

  void clearBPM() {
    setState(() {
      _heartBPM = 0;
    });
  }

  void revokePermissions() async {
    try {
      await FitKit.revokePermissions();
      permissions = await FitKit.hasPermissions(DataType.values);
      print('revokePermissions: success');
    } catch (e) {
      print('revokePermissions: $e');
    }
  }

  void read() async {
    try {
      permissions = await FitKit.requestPermissions(DataType.values);
      if (!permissions) {
        print('requestPermissions: failed');
        setState(() {
          bodyHBPM = '0';
        });
      } else {
        if(await FitKit.requestPermissions(DataType.values)){
          final now = DateTime.now();
          final startOfDay = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
          final results = await FitKit.read(
            DataType.HEART_RATE,
            dateFrom: startOfDay,
            dateTo: now,
          );
          startTimer();
          // print(results);
          clearBPM();
          addBPM(results);
        }

        print('readAll: success');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('readAll: $e');
    }
  }
```

It was successful a week ago until I ran it again today and got this error:

```
readAll: PlatformException(FitKit, 5000: Application needs OAuth consent from the user, null, null)
```

What am I missing? The OAuth credentials have been created in the Google Console and it hasn't been changed since the last time I got it working.

Comment: I havec the same issue, do find any solution ?

Comment: Did you add scope in your code? If that is the case then you also need to update the OAuth consent screen and make sure you included the scope specified here.
https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization#OAuth2Authorizing